# Is there such a thing as an "Encoding Language"?

Tags: encoding, categories

I know that there are at least two types of coding languages: *markup* and *programming*. HTML is an example of the former, Python an example of the latter.

Is there such a thing as an *encoding language*? An example of this could be Unicode.

Here's a concept tree I made to help illustrate my point:

[image: 1]

Comment: no, encodings tell the system how to render text it's not something that an upper level user would access or need to access directly. Basically "A computer cannot store "letters", "numbers", "pictures" or anything else. The only thing it can store and work with are bits. " (from http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and encoding is the pathway between what the user/programmer see's and those bits.

Comment: No, why would there be? What kind of answer are you looking for and how would that help you?

Comment: @scrappedcola: I know what encodings are.

Comment: @CodeCaster: (1) See my comment below to svrnm's answer. (2) It would help me because I'm curious. Does there need to be any other reason?

Comment: I asked those questions to gauge your intentions and figure out whether you're making a mistake in your train of though. You're asking _"Can I call a cow a milk tree?"_, which makes no sense, and your answers to my question don't change that. If you're going to stand by your comments, the answer simply is _"No"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes my comments do reflect what I said. Again, check out [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660343/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-encoding-language?noredirect=1#comment55130863_33660533) to svrnm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode and ASCII are [character sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) and no languages, so they only define the amount of symbols you can use and display.

For the other two (Markup and Programming Languages) it depends on your definition of *language*. Maybe this is interesting for you: [formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language)

Comment: Three things: (1) "... so they only define the amount of symbols you can use and display." Wouldn't that merely be an example of syntax and spelling? A "language" is really just a set of discrete units of information (whether that be characters ("graphemes") or sounds ("phomemes" or visual data (e.g. sign language) that are used in certain ways according to syntax and spelling so as to convey information from one medium to another (e.g. person-to-person, computer-to-computer, etc.).

Comment: (2) "For the other it depends on your definition of language." For the other what?

Comment: (3) "Maybe this is interesting for you: [formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language)" I'm already aware of what a formal language is. Thanks, though. 

Comment: I made an edit regarding (2). Regarding (1): The amount of symbols you can use does not tell you anything about syntax and spelling, e.g. "äüö" is legal unicode but illegal for ascii.